# Ordered Doubly Linked List Insertion

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm working on a school project right now. It's an ordered(ascending) doubly linked list. I just wrote the Insert operation on it but I feel like the way I wrote it isn't that great.

```
void OrdListClass::Insert(ItemType item)
{
    if(Find(item))
    {
        //throw DuplicateKeyException;
    }//End Duplicate Key Check
    else
    {
        //Due to Find, currPos points to the node that we're inserting AFTER
        node* newNode = new node;
        newNode->data = item;

        if(currPos == nullptr)
        {
            //We're inserting at the head.
            newNode->prev = nullptr;
            newNode->next = head;
            head->prev = newNode;
            head = newNode;
        }
        else if(currPos->next == nullptr)
        {
            //We're inserting at the tail
            newNode->next = nullptr;
            newNode->prev = tail;
            tail->next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            //We're inserting in the middle of the list.
            newNode->prev = currPos;
            newNode->next = currPos->next;
            currPos->next->prev = newNode;
            currPos->next = newNode;
        }
        currPos = newNode;
    }//End Not Duplicate Else
}//End Insert
```

EDIT: Of note.. ItemType is just a typedef for an int.

```
bool OrdListClass::Find(/*IN*/ItemType searchKey)
{
    //Skip operations if empty.
    if(IsEmpty()) return false;

    currPos = head;
    while(!EndOfList())
    {
        if(currPos->data == searchKey)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (currPos->data > searchKey)
        {
            currPos = currPos->prev;
            return false;
        }
        //else continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about the `Find` function? Is it used elsewhere in the class? Is it public?

Comment: It is public. It'll return true if the item is found in the list, and it makes currPos point to the node that the item is in. If the item is NOT found in the list, it returns false, and currPos points to the node in front of where it should be inserted. Example in case it's not clear: List of:{[7][9]} Find(8) would return false and currPos would be pointing at the [7] node, so if find was called via Insert(8); it will make the list {[7][8][9]}. I put the source for Find in the OP.

Comment: I agree with @tenterhook's answer in that it's weird to have `Find` implictly update some `currPos` member and have `Insert` depend on this behavior.  It'd be much better to have the lookup function return a node more explicitly, through a return value or out parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I think your `Insert` function is about as tight as you can make it without getting into strictly-organizational functions to tuck the list details (`head`, `tail`) and node details (`next`, `prev`) out of sight. Not a big deal for this one function and probably not for the class overall.

If I could make one suggestion, though, it would be that you reconsider having the `Find` function serve as both a match-finding function (returning `true` or `false` accordingly) and a state-modifying function that updates member `currPos`.

If I saw the definition of `Find` in the header, I would wonder why it was not a `const` function since the name and return value give me no reason to think it's modifying the object itself -- surely it just returns `true` if a match is found and nothing else. Also, since the list is ordered, it would seem that `currPos` must always be updated before any meaningful modification is performed: it determines where the current insert/delete occurs (not an arbitrary insert/delete like against `head` or `tail`) so `currPos` has no value to insertion/deletion before or after the call and thus no value as a member. So `currPos` as a member seems like unnecessary temporary storage at best and error-prone storage at worst.

Assuming my assessment of `Find` and `currPos` are fair, consider removing member `currPos` and adding a function to manage the list search without storing the node or the match flag in the object, like so:

```
node* OrdListClass::FindNode(/*IN*/ItemType searchKey, bool& matchFound) const
{
    matchFound = false;

    //Skip operations if empty.
    if(IsEmpty()) return nullptr;

    node* currPos = head;

    while(currPos != nullptr)
    {
        if(currPos->data == searchKey)
        {
            matchFound = true;
            return currPos;
        }
        else if (currPos->data > searchKey)
        {
            currPos = currPos->prev;
            return currPos;
        }
    }
}
```

`Find` then becomes:

```
bool OrdListClass::Find(/*IN*/ItemType searchKey) const
{
    bool matchFound = false;
    //FindNode is only called to determine if there is an exact match.
    FindNode(searchKey, matchFound);
    return matchFound;
}
```

And `Insert` becomes:

```
void OrdListClass::Insert(ItemType item)
{
    bool matchFound = false;
    node* currPos = FindNode(item, matchFound);

    if (matchFound)
    {
      //Nothing to insert.
      return;
    }

    //currPos points to the node that we're inserting AFTER
    node* newNode = new node;
    newNode->data = item;

    if(currPos == nullptr)
    {
        //We're inserting at the head.
        newNode->prev = nullptr;
        newNode->next = head;
        head->prev = newNode;
        head = newNode;
    }
    else if(currPos->next == nullptr)
    {
        //We're inserting at the tail
        newNode->next = nullptr;
        newNode->prev = tail;
        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        //We're inserting in the middle of the list.
        newNode->prev = currPos;
        newNode->next = currPos->next;
        currPos->next->prev = newNode;
        currPos->next = newNode;
    }
}//End Insert
```

There are alternative ways to implement `FindNode` rather than passing a `bool` reference for the matching flag (e.g., returning something like a `NodeSearchResult` object that contains the flag and the node together), but the gist is that `FindNode` is a function that manages the insertion/deletion point without resorting to using a member for temporary storage.

Whether or not you choose to go with something like this, I hope it gives you something to think about. Otherwise, like I said, `Insert` itself seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

2 questions:

1. What is the expected logic for inserting the first node to an empty
   list?
2. Is `nullptr` just a typedef to  `NULL`, or you used the 'dummy node'
   approach? If it is `NULL`, you cannot move your `currPos` there -
   you should be 'in the list', and check next/prev for null-ness.

Comment: `nullptr` is a C++11 feature: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Null_pointer_constant (though he could have aliased it to NULL I suppose... >.<)